# Can't format the JSON data

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Below is the sample JSON data that i obtained from API call. But when i try to format the JSON data, i couldn't able to do it.

```json
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": [
        {
            "status": "3",
            "name": "Windows",
            "triggers": [
                { "triggerid": "11234" },
                { "triggerid": "5465" },
                { "triggerid": "56465" },
                { "triggerid": "56465" },
                { "triggerid": "54364" },
                { "triggerid": "564654" },
                { "triggerid": "564365" },
                { "triggerid": "5434" },
                { "triggerid": "54354" },
                { "triggerid": "5454" },
                { "triggerid": "5645" },
                { "triggerid": "543654" },
                { "triggerid": "546543" }
            ],
            "items": [
                { "name": "connection check" },
                { "name": "Version of apache running" },
                { "name": "Average IOPS " },
                { "name": "Average wrtie speed" },
                { "name": "file in speed" }
            ],
            "templateid": "456434",
            "discoveries": []
        },
        {
            "status": "3",
            "name": "linux_server",
            "triggers": [
                { "triggerid": "11234" },
                { "triggerid": "5465" },
                { "triggerid": "56465" },
                { "triggerid": "56465" },
                { "triggerid": "54364" },
                { "triggerid": "564654" },
                { "triggerid": "564365" },
                { "triggerid": "5434" },
                { "triggerid": "54354" },
                { "triggerid": "5454" },
                { "triggerid": "5645" },
                { "triggerid": "543654" },
                { "triggerid": "123543" }
            ],
            "items": [
                { "name": "connection check" },
                { "name": "Version of docker running" },
                { "name": "Average IOPS " },
                { "name": "Average wrtie speed" },
                { "name": "file in speed" }
            ],
            "templateid": "456434",
            "discoveries": []
        }
    ]
}
```

My code:

```
output = requests.post(url, data=apache_data, headers=headers)
content_out = json.loads(output.content)
content_out = json.dumps(content_out)

for key in content_out .items():
  print(key)
```

Error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`

i want the "`name":"windows"` ............ until `"discoveries": []}` as one dictionary  . Like that `"name": "linux_server"`........ until `"discoveries": []}` as a another dictionary.. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, format your code and define `template_out` variable.

Comment: The JSON example you've pasted here is missing at least a trailing `]}`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)? You can get access to the JSON as a dictionary by calling `output.json()`

So I think with your code, it would look something like this:

```python
output = requests.post(url, data=apache_data, headers=headers)

for result in output.json()['result']:
    print(result['name'], result['status'], result['templateid'])
```

And here's the output:

```
Windows 3 456434
linux_server 3 456434
```

In your example, `Windows` and `linux_server` are two dictionaries in the `result` list.

Answer (score 0):

You've left in a line of debug / experiment code that converts the parsed JSON that you wanted back into a string. Try removing that:

```
output = requests.post(url, data=apache_data, headers=headers )
# This parses your JSON correctly.
content_out = json.loads(ouput.content)
# This line turns your parsed JSON back into a string. You don't need this.
# content_out = json.dumps(content_out)

for key in content_out.items():
    print (key)
```